# How to insert 'n' columns in a matrix

Tags: r, matrix, cbind

Suppose I have the following matrix

```
A = diag(5)
A
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    0    0    0    0
[2,]    0    1    0    0    0
[3,]    0    0    1    0    0
[4,]    0    0    0    1    0
[5,]    0    0    0    0    1
```

and I want to add the first column of the matrix `A` in the `new_A` (for `n` times, suppose that `n = 3`, but in my case, `n` can be bigger)

```
new_A
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8]
[1,]    1    1    1    1    0    0    0    0
[2,]    0    0    0    0    1    0    0    0
[3,]    0    0    0    0    0    1    0    0
[4,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    0
[5,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1
```

How can I add the first column of the `A` for `n` times in the  `new_A` automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Repeat 1 `n` times and append the remaining columns.

```
n = 3
A[, c(rep(1, n + 1), 2:ncol(A))]

#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8]
#[1,]    1    1    1    1    0    0    0    0
#[2,]    0    0    0    0    1    0    0    0
#[3,]    0    0    0    0    0    1    0    0
#[4,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    0
#[5,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1
```